# How to charge multiple High Voltage Li-ion Batteries

Tags: batteries, circuit-design, analog, battery-charging, power-electronics

I want to charge six DC 80v/30A lithium ion battery with BMS using single phase power DC supply source.

Batteries need (6*2.4 kWh. Charge efficiency about .8:) 18kW roughly power.

Power Source has 100V/300A sink capacity.

Mın Charging for battery 30A, and discharging 150A.

I need a circuit to charge one or six batteries at the same time. So I don't want to buy a charger instead design it.

Time is not so critical, but must be less then an hour for charging.

My question is for this purpose what is the most effective battery charging circuit?

Regards.

Comment: What type of batteries? BMS? Wanna build or buy a charger? Charge how fast? This site is give/take ;-)

Comment: @datenheim Thanks. I edited my question.

Comment: (More like 80V/30**Ah**?) Effective: does charge to capacity. Useful: Tries not to cause damage. From deep discharge, you are looking at 6*2.4 KWh. Charge efficiency about .8: you are looking at 18 KW, minimum.

Comment: There's still no information about the type of battery.

Comment: To specify a charger, the BMS specification is of secondary concern. What is the nominal voltage and rated capacity of the batteries, what battery life/discharge depth are you aiming for?

Comment: (To improve the usefulness of answers as far as you are concerned, give hints to the extent of power EE competence you command, e.g., add information to your profile.)

Comment: Back of the envelope type of design or ready to build a prototype to put to stress tests? 3-phase input. Heat management. Additional battery supervision, depending on BMS or just to play safe.

Comment: Why not telling the battery make and model? What power source (mains voltage, 3-phase or single-phase, or solar) is available? Th 1 hour is for charging, or for building the charger?

Comment: You want the batteries charged in under and hour, but say you can only provide 8kW charging power, so that isn't possible. What is the battery chemistry? Most li-ions shouldn't be charged at more than 1C, as doing so will harm the batteries signficnatly, so that another reason it'll take more than an hour to charge them. You haven't told us what voltage the batteries are charged at, just that their nominal is 80V.

Comment: ([Puffafish's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/649414/how-to-charge-multiple-80-v-li-ion-batteries#comment1724457_649414) pertains to [this revision](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/649414/5).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't reinvent the wheel. Just parallel.

Lithium chargers are extremely hard.  Not to be unkind, but I am pretty sure you don't have the technical chops to design a lithium battery from scratch, because you would be asking different questions if you did.

However, this isn't necessarily a problem.  It's perfectly normal to build lithium battery packs in series/parallel arrangements.  You could simply buy one commercial, off the shelf charger and then connect to 1 to 6 batteries in parallel.  It will charge all six at a lower rate than 1, however it will tend to favor the more-discharged battery(ies).  Make sure each battery has a BMS to protect it from overcharge.

### How much power do you need?

Now, as far as rate: You have an 80 volt battery with 30 amp-hours.  That is 2400 watt-hours or 2.4 kilowatt-hours, with inefficiencies 3 kWH.  You want to do that in an hour, so you will need 3000 watts. All six batteries will need 18 kWH.

That will take an EV 55 miles.   So we are free to think of it that way: one battery is 9 miles of EV charging and all six is 55 miles.   Well, we can just look at it that way, such as [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s).  Here's a snap from it.

[image]

*Volts x amps is 125% of watts because of a NEC/CEC requirement for a 125% derate. See NEC 625.42.*

So your needs *just about* correspond to the absolute max charge rate possible with Level 2 EV charging.

This is all the more reason to avoid designing something that is out of the league of every contributor to this forum (except *maybe* one or two of them). People are still homebrewing EVs, so there are many companies offering battery charger modules (which sit inside the car) as COTS solutions.  That's what I'd go for.

Comment: Thanks Harper for your response. "Connect 1 to 6 batteries in parallel" but how you control the current; there will be different voltage levels and current changes & increases suddenly, is it not dangerous?

Comment: @terbus5: (case 0: single battery - no problem) case 1: multiple batteries, discharged connected in parallel (P): charge in parallel 1b: multiple batteries, same chemistry, discharged in series (S) or in a useful combination of P&S: *should* work, take care when connecting in P - else use a multi-output charger, or two smaller ones so you're still able to operate while one isn't available.

Comment: @terbus5 you need to figure that out in pack design.  Really each pack will need to have an onboard BMS and ideally an onboard charger that can limit supply current.  As for danger, *you're the one who specified lithium* which instantly raised the difficulty by ten orders of magnitude.  Lithium is hard. Samsung and Boeing screwed it up. Don't always listen to Elon Musk, but do so now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN90HYiFpAw

Comment: @graybeard the problem with charging in series is we can't count on the batteries having the same state-of-charge. Thus parallel is the better bet, as current will favor the more discharged battery.  However this should still have some on-battery protection and charge control to account for differencees in pack aging.

Comment: @terbus5 the feedback here is **do not do what you're trying to do** i.e. do not make your own charging solution. You simply do not have the necessary skills yet to do it, and if you try to do it, you'll probably burn your house down (or die). The solution involves very high powers and voltages - in many places it would probably be illegal to do this without a license, because its really dangerous. At best, your solution will heat up to much and burn itself up, at worst all of your batteries will explode and destroy whatever structure they are inside, with a fire that cant be extuinguished.

Comment: (My hair won't turn *gray*.) I did not mention charging in series.

Comment: If everyone think Response is safe and easiest solution "one charger will charge all parallel connected batteries may be 1 or 2 or 6 " i will Accept @Harper-ReinstateMonica solution.

Comment: @terbus5 again the batteries would need some sort of onboard protection, BMS or ideally onboard charge limiter. The consequences for "not bothering with all that stuff" are *extreme* on packs this size. If it relates to a house, you may need permits and definitely need an insurance rider.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica What is different using a DC Power Supply instead of buying Battery Charger ?

Comment: @terbus5 one just makes DC power.  The other regulates power to the precise needs of a particular type of battery. If you just put a DC power supply on the battery, it can be destroyed or catch fire.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks now its clear, Could you pls advice me a charger for this requirements?